# How to wrap calls of every member function of a class in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Herb Sutter asked this question in a talk about C++11 and concurrency (See [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism))

The key idea here is to have a non locking class `X` where every function call should be decorated with a lock that is unlocked after a function.

However, Herb Sutter drifts then off and presents a functor based approach. I'm wondering if it is even possible with C++11 to wrap each function call with lock and unlock of a class in a generic way (not wrapping every function call manually).

```
class X {
  public:
    X() = default;
    void somefunc(arg1 x1, arg2 x2, ...);
    void somefunc2(arg1 x1, arg2 x2, ...);
    /* and more */
};

// herb admits one way to make all functions *available*
// in another class is by derivation

class XX : public X {
  public:
    XX() = default;
    // all functions available in NON overloaded form...
};
```

there is also the decorator pattern

```
class XXX {
  public:
    XXX(X &x) : m_x(x) {}

    // explicitly call each wrapped function ... done for each class separately.
    void somefunc(arg1 x1, arg2 x2, ...);
    void somefunc2(arg1 x1, arg2 x2, ...);
  private:
    class X& m_x;
};
```

but is there something like this possible:

```
template<>
class wrap_everything;

wrap_everything<X> x;
x.somefunc(x1,x2,...); // this is then locked.
```

for the sake of completeness this is herb sutter's functor based approach:

```
template <class T> class locker {
  private:
    mutable T m_t;
    mutable std::mutex m_m;
  public:
    locker( T t = T{} ) : m_t(t) {}
    template <typename F>
    auto operator()(F f) const -> decltype(f(m_t)) {
      std::lock_guard<mutex> _{m_m};
      return f(t);
    }
};


// usage 
locker<std::string> s;
s([](string &s) {
   s += "foobar";
   s += "barfoo";
});
```

Comment: At least with some compilers (e.g., gcc) the compiler can do this with no code modification. Usually used for profiling, but you can have it insert a call to specified functions before and after each function call. Would still be non-trivial for the code to sort out where you wanted locks and where you really didn't though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I guess this is fatal for every maintainer to have to look for the locks somewhere else than in the code.

Comment: @Alex Great question.  I remember when Sutter tantalized with this at C++ and Beyond 2012, and then veered off, as you say.  Maybe he was dropping hints as to the C++14 feature set.

Comment: Most probably that's completely impossible inside the language rules. But as well as I appreciate the theoretical nature of this question, I hope you are aware of the fact that the functor based approach is in most situation more useful and appropriate anyway. It's not just the *possible* way, it's also the *better* way.

Comment: Wow. What would the lock be based upon? How would you handle problems like priority inversion and deadlock?

Comment: @Alex: Probably. Certainly wasn't meant as a practical suggestion (thus posted as comment, not answer).

Comment: @ChristianRau he even said in the talk, that the approach to do this to every function is not overly useful as nesting of function calls might lead to recursive locking and calling multiple functions from the same object or the problem of sequential calls that should be locked but then aren't. I'm thinking about this because this would be the perfect solution for any mocking framework.

Comment: @RamRajamony this question is not meant to be exclusive for locking. but the possibility to do so within the language is of great value for other problems.

Comment: Is it me, or did you switch `t` and `m_t` in both the initialization list of the constructor of locker, and in its `operator()`? Also, in your `operator()` the `lock_guard` should be initialized using `m_m` instead of `m`

Comment: What `class &X m_x;` supposed to mean? Did you mean `class X& m_x;`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question is about the EXECUTE-AROUND pattern.  I made a generic (but only barely tested) implementation of EXECUTE-AROUND POINTER at https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/exec_around.h

This allows:

```
struct X { void f() { } };
auto x = mutex_around<X>();
x->f();  // locks a mutex for duration of call to X::f
```

A more in depth explaination on how the family of *execute around* patterns work can be found [here (pdf)](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/papers/europlop/ExecutingAroundSequences.pdf)

Comment: I'm not sure yet whether that's what I'm looking for, but it makes me excited already!

Comment: +1 Hah, right! The chaining behaviour of `operator->`! Very nice solution.

Comment: The link to the pdf is dead :(

Answer (score 11):

I don't believe there is a portable generic way to do this in current C++.  If templates were capable of taking an overload set as a template parameter (which I'd very much like to see in C++14 for many reasons), and the call site could be changed from `x.y(z)` to `x->y(z)`, I think it could probably be done with a proxy and an overloaded `operator->`.  Otherwise, the best generic way of doing something like this is using Aspect Oriented Programming frameworks for C++ (such as AspectC++).

Being able to wrap each member function call is only really half the story on this, though.  According to the **Interface Principle**, the interface of a class is the functions that mention a class and are supplied with a class.  This includes public member functions, friend functions, and free functions in the same namespace as the class.  Being able to pass instances to such functions in a wrapped way is a much more subtle problem than merely wrapping member function calls, which is where Sutter's approach shows real power and flexibility.

Comment: +1 for mentioning AOP, which aims precisely at answering this kind of questions.

Comment: [Classic Stroustrup paper](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf) that discusses the proxy+`operator->` technique for bracketing member function calls.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to do exactly what you want, but something close is doable.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
  public:
    void one (int x) {
        std::cout << "Called Foo::one(" << x << ")\n";
    }
    void two (int x, double y) {
        std::cout << "Called Foo::two(" << x << ", " << y << ")\n";
    }
};

class ScopeDecorator {
  public:
    ScopeDecorator() {
        std::cout << "Enter scope\n";
    }
    ~ScopeDecorator() {
        std::cout << "Exit scope\n";
    }
};

template <class Wrappee, class Wrapper>
class Wrap {
  public:
    Wrap (Wrappee& w) : wrappee(w) {}
    template <typename rettype, typename... argtype>
        rettype call (rettype (Wrappee::*func)(argtype...), argtype... args)
        {
            Wrapper wrapper;
            return (wrappee.*func)(args...);
        }
  private:
    Wrappee& wrappee;
};

int main ()
{
    Foo foo;
    Wrap<Foo, ScopeDecorator> wfoo(foo);
    wfoo.call(&Foo::one, 42);
    wfoo.call(&Foo::two, 32, 3.1415);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I also wrote a generic implementation of the execute around idom:

https://github.com/ArnaudBienner/ExecuteAround

https://github.com/ArnaudBienner/ExecuteAround/blob/master/ExecuteAround.h

with an example on how to make a thread safe object from it:
https://github.com/ArnaudBienner/ExecuteAround/blob/master/main.cpp#L78

Just for the record, since the one provided by Jonathan already looks great, and mine probably needs some clean up.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible and it was proposed long back by none other than Stroustrup and his original proposal is still available. See [www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf)

Basically the idea is to override operator `->` at 2 levels and lock/unlock mutex in the constructor and destructor of temporary object that is returned by first operator `->`.

The second operator `->` will return the pointer of object on which the method will be invoked.