# Are C++11 lambdas themselves subject to RAII automatic deallocation?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, raii

I'd like to write a class method that optionally accepts a lambda to customize its behavior.  So when using this class, I'm wondering if I need to worry about the lambda itself going out of scope?

The lambda would not reference any external vars, so I'm not worried about the scope of the vars, only about the scope of the lambda itself, which I'd store a reference to in the class.

Do I need to worry about how/where the lambda itself was created?

Comment: I don't think that the function itself will ever go out of scope. A lambda is just shiny syntax for a Functor object. And it will boil down to a function pointer. Don't hold a reference to a lambda, but keep a copy. If the capture list is empty it'll be cheap.

Comment: In general, these kinds of questions are best served *with code samples* of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its an instance of its own unique class type. It follows the same rules of object lifetime that any other instance does. Whether you need to "worry" about that is dependent entirely on how you're using it, which we have no knowledge of.

Comment: functors should generally be handled by value, rather than by reference. Lambda expressions are just a handy way to create a functor, so you should handle the result of a lambda as a value as well.

Answer (score 2):

References, outside of narrow situations, do not extend the lifetime of the thing you are referencing.

Using a reference to something whose lifetime has expired is undefined behavior.

The undefined behavior of a stateless lambda may be "I don't even use my `this` pointer", so you may be fine.  However, if you know that the lambda is going to be stateless, you could instead store a function pointer.

Now, your class, in order to store an actual lambda, must be templated on that lambda type.  And if it is a stateless lambda, it is almost certainly going to be as small (or smaller) than a reference to that lambda.  So why not just store a copy of the lambda?

If instead you are storing a `std::function<void()>` or the like, that is not a reference to a lambda.  That is a type erasure object that wraps a copy of a lambda.  Storing a reference to a `std::function<void()>` after it goes out of scope would be a bad idea, as it is *not* stateless, and will go off and read garbage memory when you try to invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Might not completely fill in your answer, but have a look how herb sutter has solved a similar RAII with lambdas solution. See also this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859519/how-to-make-wrap-every-member-function-call-of-a-class-in-c11)

```
template <class T> class locker {
private:
  mutable T m_t; // Copies the lambda here.
  mutable std::mutex m_m;
public:
  locker( T t = T{} ) : m_t(t) {}
  template <typename F>
  auto operator()(F f) const -> decltype(f(m_t)) {
    std::lock_guard<mutex> _{m_m};
    return f(t);
  }
};


// usage 
locker<std::string> s;
s([](string &s) {
  s += "foobar";
  s += "barfoo";
});
```

The important part about this example is that the Lambda is copied. You shouldn't hold references to lambdas as the function itself will be in the read-only sections of your program. The only data that the lambda holds is a function pointer and its captures. If you do have captures you are dependent on the scope of your lambda and if this runs out of scope you'll be accessing memory, that has been released already.

Comment: Lambdas don't hold function pointers: their `operator()` is part of their type, not their run time state.

Comment: @YakK: I'll rephrase that, the point I'm trying to make is, that your compiler will generate code that jumps to a label and this label is possibly not in the read only section of your binary.

Comment: what ?  Huh ?  There is no more reason for the lambda's code to be "not in the read only section of the binary" than there is for any other code to be "not in the read only section of your binary" as of C++11.  (There are some proposals in C++1y, like function pointers to stateful lambda invocation, that could require something like that).

Comment: the OP was referring to this by "the scope of the lambda itself". the only thing that might not be in the read only section is a label that is stored, copies or references to variables in the capture list. everything else is RO. it's not as if you'd require self-modifying code or ram functions to achieve lambdas that might leak or go out of scope.

Comment: @Alex: "Jumps to a label" implies that the label is in a code section; either that's a read-only code section or it's a read/write code section. The latter means self-modifying code. Your 2 comments are contradicting.