# Automatically copy all methods

Tags: c++, templates

So say I have a class A:

```
class A{
  public:
    void DoSomething();
    void DoSomethingElse(int x);
};
```

And I want to have another class Proxy:

```
class Proxy{
    A* a;
  public:
    void DoSomething(){ a->DoSomething(); }
    void DoSomethingElse(int x){ a->DoSomethingElse(x); }
};
```

But the hitch is that I want to be able to make `Proxy` a templated class so that I can do this kind of transform to **any** class....

Is there some sort of trick I can do?

A detailed description:

Basically this proxy would take every single method in the class and create a method with the same name and use the pointer to complete the method....You cannot use inheritance because that increases the size, which is actually what I am trying to avoid here.

I am basically asking is there something akin to overriding the dot operator like in this question: [Why can't you overload the '.' operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520035/why-cant-you-overload-the-operator-in-c)  (The answer in there was "no")

Comment: @kfsone I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: You want just a templated class?  Or maybe you are getting at inheritance.

Comment: @TrevorHickey Well the major difference between this and inheritance is the __size__ of the resulting class, which is why I am doing it this way. (the size of proxy is sizeof(ptr_t))

Comment: You could provide `operator->`, but other than that, no you can't.

Comment: What kind of transform do you want to do ?

Comment: @JohanBoule I am trying to take each method of class `A`, create an associated method, which calls original `A` method....the reason is size, inheriting `A` could cause a huge size, while just doing this transform (with a pointer to `A`) has a size of a ptr

Comment: @JohanBoule I edited my post a little to clairfy

Comment: The only way I could think of would be code generation (parse the original class and create a proxy class from it). In other languages you could probably use runtime reflection to perform that task, but not in C++. And inheritance and templates won't help you, because they don't deliver you a method list.

Comment: @Matthias247 That is what I was afraid of....but I will do that if I need to

Comment: Why do you want to encapsulate the pointer rather than using it directly, or use a smart pointer ? We're probably not seeing the whole picture that leads to your question.

Comment: Hurb Sutter uses a functor based approach to do something like this.  You can see an SO question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859519/how-to-wrap-calls-of-every-member-function-of-a-class-in-c11

Answer (score 0):

Consider two types with the same functionality.

```
struct A{
    void DoSomething(){
      std::cout << "A::DoSomething\n";
    }
    void DoSomethingElse(int x){
      std::cout << "A::DoSomething(int)\n";
    }
};

struct B{
    void DoSomething(){
      std::cout << "B::DoSomething\n";
    }
    void DoSomethingElse(int x){
      std::cout << "B::DoSomething(int)\n";
    }
};
```

Your templated proxy could be the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Proxy{
    T a;
  public:
    void DoSomething(){ a.DoSomething(); }
    void DoSomethingElse(int x){ a.DoSomethingElse(x); }
};
```

It would be used like so:

```
int main(){
  Proxy<B> b;
  Proxy<A> a;

  a.DoSomething();
  a.DoSomethingElse(0);

  b.DoSomething();
  b.DoSomethingElse(0);
}
```

**result:**

```
A::DoSomething
A::DoSomething(int)
B::DoSomething
B::DoSomething(int)
```

Comment: I guess I might not have stressed this enough but this has to work with **any** class you name it....std::vector, myRandomClass, etc..  This only works with those that have those particular functions....I will try to make this more clear in the question

Comment: So if the class doesn't have the particular method, what do you expect Proxy to do when you call it?  I think I see what you are getting at.  You want proxy to inherit the methods from whatever it derives from.

Comment: Exactly, except with out inheriting all of the size that is associated with inheriting

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible in C++, but it's also not useful, because a Proxy instance would not also be an A instance -- you could not pass Proxy instances to methods that required As.

In fact, there wouldn't be any thing that could possibly call your Proxy object until you *wrote* those calls.  Given that you have to write all the proxy calls, is it really so much extra work to write the proxy methods you're calling?

Comment: Well actually it could be useful if you gave another template parameter of which is a base class of `A`, but yeah I do see your point